# Truffle Flattener creates empty flat file

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-migration, truffle-contract, truffle-deployment

Using trufffle-flattener, I am trying to create a flat file merging all the related solidity based codes. After executing the flattening scripts, I see only the empty flat file getting created. Could you please assist me in resolving this issue ?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 8):

Try to use output parameter:

```
truffle-flattener .\contracts\WetherCrowdsale.sol --output WetherCrowdsale_flat.sol
```

Comment: sudo npm install -g truffle-flattener to use above solution